# Tagging friends in Facebook video IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm developing an IOS app that allows the user to upload a video on Facebook, I want also to allow user to tag his friends in video. I found how to tag friends in a photo, how to post something and tagging a friend, how to upload videos, but I can't find any solution to tag a friend in a video. Does anyone solved this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, you have to post the video without tagging, and after that you can get the id of your post and add tags. Here is the code

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags/%@?access_token=token", idPost,[[selectedFriends objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]] parameters:res HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ok!!");
    }
}];
```